# Generating an ID for each result using Linq

Tags: entity-framework, linq, asp.net-web-api2

I am creating a web API to display a list of loyalty programs in our system. Each loyalty program has a super long GUID that i would like to somehow turn into a simple Unique ID.

The purpose the the API is to display each item with an id, the end user can then use the same command and that ID number to get more information about the loyalty program.

In SQL i would use something like the Rank Over but I am not sure how to apply that here.

```
var ReturnedLoyalty = from d in db.LoyaltyCampaigns
                                  where d.CampaignStart < DateTime.Now && d.CampaignStop >= DateTime.Now
                                  orderby d.CampaignName ascending
                                  select new { d.CampaignGUID, d.CampaignName };
```

I would like to subsitute the d.campaignguid for a simple set of numbers like 1,2,3... etc.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql-identity-property

Comment: You could so this with a `.Select((value, index)=>...})` (linq to objects) ... but if you want an integer based ID... add an integer based ID.  Otherwise the numbers can change over time and that would confuse the hell out of people.

Comment: The SQL table is created by a third party software vendor. Their software used the GUID column behind the scenes and they have it set as the indentity column on the table. So i am unable to create a new identity on the SQL table.

Comment: I'd still  guess yo uadd a column even if you have to maintain the ID with a trigger or some other event as if anything is removed, added or renamed these numbers will change.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately query comprehension syntax doesn't support the two argument version of `select`, but you can use it after the query:

```
var ReturnedLoyalty = (from d in db.LoyaltyCampaigns
                       where d.CampaignStart < DateTime.Now && d.CampaignStop >= DateTime.Now
                       orderby d.CampaignName ascending
                       select d.CampaignName).Select((name, index) => new { ID = index, CampaignName = name});
```